# Is there a line break in python like there's a <br> in HTML

Tags: python, line-breaks

Are there line breaks in python? I know I can put a print("") to make a new line, but is there an attribute for a line break in python?

Comment: You mean the newline character `\n`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `\n`

eg. `print('line1\nline2')`

Read up on [escape sequences](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp)